# How do I resize my textures in LibGDX?(Android)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, resolution

I'm starting to use LibGDX, and wanted to easily port my game to different screen size(in Android). I have a background texture, which I want to scale to the currently used resolution. The game works on 1920x1080, but when I use a lower resolution the texture is cut, how do I change it to the currently screen size?

I use

```
batch = new SpriteBatch();
bkTexture = new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu.png")),0 , 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

and

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
stage.act(delta);
batch.begin();
batch.draw(bkTexture, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
batch.end();
stage.draw();
```

Comment: How about using a StretchViewport?

Answer (score 0):

Add filter on your texture?

```
myTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

bkTexture = new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu.png")),0 , 0);

instead of

bkTexture = new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu.png")),0 , 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

Using the 2nd line you extract a texture region with the size Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() at position 0,0 of the menu.png texture.

Comment: I changed TextureRegion to Texture and importing to bkTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu.png")); and it works fine. Now I have problems with changing the proportion;